# How to filter array of array based on another subarray

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to filter an array of array, based on another subarray. I am giving example below to make the requirement more clear. Please note that order of filterArray is important. I can `iterate myArrayofArray using for loop, and then compare the element of each iterated element with filterArray`. But I think `Filter` can be used in this case to get the resultArray. But a bit confused, how I'll implement it.

```
myArrayofArray = [[1,0,2], [1,2,0], [1,3,4], [1,2,1]]
filterArray = [1,0]
resultArray = [1,0,2]
```

Comment: So you want to return the array that contains both of the numbers in `filterArray`?

Comment: You haven't really described how exactly the filter array is used. The example doesn't make it clear, either.

Comment: @Alexander: each element of myArrayofArray will be compared with filter array. `filterArray[0]` will be compared with `myArrayofArray[0][0]` and so on. Hope, its clear now.

Comment: ah. Do you expect a single match, or multiple? `first(where:)` might be more appropriate than `filter(_:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be

```
let result = myArrayofArray.filter { $0.starts(with: filterArray) }
```

This will return a `[[Int]]` with zero or more matching arrays.

Comment: Thanks, Now I can use `result.flatMap({$0})` to get the desired result :)